# How to go to the end of the file?

Tags: fortran

I have opened a file to write a number. I have to write the number at the end of the file so

how to go to the last line to write on it?

Comment: Q: Does your FORTRAN implementation have "fseek()"?  Or can you just OPEN in "APPEND" mode?

Answer (score 7):

You should open the file with

```
open(..., position="append",...)
```

Alternatively, you can inquire for the size of the file

```
inquire(...,size=some_integer_variable,...)
```

then if the file is a direct access file, you can use this size to calculate the record number of the final record. Alternatively, if the access mode is "stream", you can use

```
write(..., pos=some_integer_variable)
```

to write starting at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the same trick for years, and would be interested in a more elegant way but I can propose you the following method. Note that it is less and less efficient as the file increases in number of lines. Note also that this part of code could endup in an elegant module dedicated to playing with input/output.

Open your file

```
open(11, file='monfichier')
```

Compute how many lines there are in your file

```
nbline = 0 ! should have been declared as an integer
do while(.true.)
  read(11,*,iostat=ios) ! ios should have been declared as an integer
  if( ios > 0 ) then
    stop 'problem somewhere'
  else if( ios < 0 ) then ! end of file is reached
    exit
  else
    nbline = nbline + 1
  end if
end do
close(11)
```

at this step, you have the total number of lines stored in variable nbline.
If you want to print something at the Nth line before the last line, then

```
open(11, file='monfichier')
do i = 1, nbline - N ! see my nota bene at the end of my answer; i and N are integers
  read(11,*)
end do
write(11,*)'hello world'
```

Et voilà !

N.B. : Please be carefull in the way you count for nbline-N or nbline-(N-1), depending on exactly what you want.

Comment: Why would you use this method when `position = 'append'` satisfies OP's requirements ?  Does this have any advantages over the straightforward approach ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark -- The only thing that I can think of is that this can be made to compile with a strict (ancient) f77 compiler (with a little tweaking -- e.g. remove `do while` in favor of statement labels, goto and if [yikes!]) whereas `position='append'` wasn't added until later (Not sure exactly how much later though).

Comment: @mgilson indeed ... One question though: isn't this method more generic in that you can write to any place you want, e.g. to the penultimate line. Can you do this using `position = ` ?

Comment: @max -- You should be able to do that with `access='stream'` and `pos=...` as demonstrated in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    subroutine to_last_rec (luout)
!   purpose: position to last record of file

    implicit none
          
    integer :: luout

    logical :: ende
          
!   first executable statement
    ende = .FALSE. 

    do while ( .NOT. ende)
        read (luout,*,end=100)
    enddo

    100 return
    end subroutine to_last_rec
```

Comment: Welcome. I suggest taking the tour. Be aware that the whole `do while ( .NOT. ende)` is just a long way to write `do`.

Answer (score -1):

PROGRAM example
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER ::  ierr

OPEN(UNIT=13,FILE="ex.dat")
CALL FSEEK(13, 0, 2, ierr)
! DO WHATEVER YOU WANT THEN

CLOSE(13)
END PROGRAM example

the call to fseek goes to the end of the file ( used like that, check the usage http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4942/6j4m3r8ti/index.html)